# How to change the home page title text in navigation menu?

Tags: wordpress

I have created a wordpress site. The home page appears in the navigation menu with the name of "Home".

I want to change this text to some other text so that in the navigation menu, it did not appear as a "Home", instead it should appear as some other text.

How will I change this text?

Comment: Hmm.. If you can't do that in the admin panel, the chance is it's hard-coded in your template file. Another really weird possibility is "cache". It's very difficult to tell you how to change it. I forgot which FTP client can "search keyword in all files in a directory". You can download all the template files down, and then use Notepad++ to find keyword in all opened files.

Comment: You could use a custom menu and change the label of the menu item.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, in order to Change the name of Home button go to:

wp-includes/post-template.php

Look for:

```
// Show Home in the menu
if ( isset($args['show_home']) && ! empty($args['show_home']) ) {
if ( true === $args['show_home'] || '1' === $args['show_home'] || 1 === $args['show_home'] )
$text = __('Home');
```

Do you see last "Home" text ? There you go, change it to whatever you want.

Comment: This is a really really bad practice since you are editing the CORE of WordPress.

Answer (score 6):

If we are talking about the default theme "Twenty Twelve":

1. Open ../twentytwelve/functions.php
2. Find twentytwelve_page_menu_args function.
3. Replace

   $args['show_home'] = true;

with

```
$args['show_home'] = "Your name";
```

Hoooray!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/changing-text-of-home-link-to-something-else

Answer (score 1):

It depends on each theme you would like to use.

For Twenty Twelve what you have to do is to set a front end page (static page) and give it a name.

then you copy functions.php to your child theme's folder and then find this:

```
/**
 * Makes our wp_nav_menu() fallback -- wp_page_menu() -- show a home link.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
function twentytwelve_page_menu_args( $args ) {
    if ( ! isset( $args['show_home'] ) )
        $args['show_home'] = true;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'twentytwelve_page_menu_args' );
```

and change this single line:

```
    $args['show_home'] = false;
```

Alternatively,
a simple solution is to go to Menus tab on the left and play with the menu options there, you can add your own if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Several years later since asking this question you can do this from the admin panel. There's a good explanation on [this](https://www.wpupgrader.com/wordpress/change-menu-navigation-settings/) website. Basically you need to go to:

**http://yourDomain/wp-admin** > **Appearance** > **Menus**. Then, under the **Menu structure** you will find **Home** - click and change the title to whatever you want. I hope this helps someone ))